# Конструктор копии для классов

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор-копирования

Пытаюсь присвоить значения вектора v1 k v2 но компилятор дает ошибку. Где ошибка? И ещё один вопрос, как перезагружать оператор присваивания ???

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.253 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Вот код

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class vector_c
    {
    private:
        int* vector1;
        int Max;
        int index;
        public:
       vector_c(int sizze)
        {
            index=0;
            Max=sizze;
            vector1 = new int[Max];
        };

        vector_c(vector_c &c)//copy construck
{

    index=c.index;
    Max = c.Max;
    vector1 = new int[Max];
    for (int i = 1; i <=Max; i++)
    {
        vector1[i] = c.vector1[i];

    }
};
        ~vector_c()
    {
        delete [] vector1;
    };
        void max_znachenie()
        {
            int index1=0;
            index1 = vector1[1];
            for(int i=1; i<=Max;i++)
            {
                if(vector1[i] > index1 )    index1 = vector1[i];
            }
            cout << index1 << endl;
        };

        void get_inf(int element)
        {
        vector1[++index]=element;
        };

    int out_inf()
    {
        return vector1[index--];
    };

    };




    int main()
    {
        vector_c v1(3);
        v1.get_inf(78);
        v1.get_inf(2);
        v1.get_inf(5);
        v1.max_znachenie();
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl << v1.out_inf() << endl << v1.out_inf() << endl << v1.out_inf() << endl;
        vector_c v2=v1;
          cout << v2.out_inf();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Когда прогоняю через дебаггер, у второго вектора Max такой же, но index не скопировался почему-то. Хотя оба целые значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прогнала ваш код в дебаггере. Есть 2 проблемы.
В конструкторе копирования копируются не все поля.
Надо добавить.

```
 index=c.index;
```

Функция переписана.

```
void get_inf(int element)
{
vector1[index++]=element;
};
```

Пример перегрузки оператора присваивания

```
    class vector_c
    {
    private:
        int* vector1;
        int Max;
        int index;
    public:
        vector_c(int sizze)
            {
                index=0;
                Max=sizze;
                vector1 = new int[Max];
            };

        vector_c& operator=(const vector_c& right) {
            //проверка на самоприсваивание
            if (this == &right) {
                return *this;
            }
            // Здесь скопируйте все значения
            return *this;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Кто заминусовал и почему?

Comment: Не  я точно. Только увидел сам. Спасибо, не знаете ли почему не хочет правильно работать конструктор копирования?

Comment: Потому что index не копируется. Добавьте index=c.index.

Comment: В out_inf() у index неопределенное значение, поэтому вылетает.

Comment: Случайно нету вариантов решения проблемы?

Comment: Добавьте index=c.index в конструктор копирования. И все равно программа вылетает, потому что по индексу 0 ничего не записано.

Comment: Да, тоже добавлял. Когда беру на вывод второй вектор, то вылетают непонятные числа

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka ответ дополнен.

Comment: Отлично работает, я тоже немного поигрался. Исправил цикл   в объекте vector_c(vector_c &c) Код поправил, тот что у меня в вопросе, выручили!!!

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka примите ответ пож